# Compositing a Hologram Button

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to create and composite a scene involving a button with some heavy effects on it. The image below is an example of what I'm trying to create.

Example Render: [image]

My current render: [image]

I have two problems with making this scene

1.) I cant figure out how to give it a voronoi or cloudy look (the increased transparency randomly thougout) without ruining the coloring or translucence and while keeping the background details clear at the same time.

2.) How to composite it so that it has the saturated glass or hologram like appearance (the glow and rgb split kind of effect) that the example image has.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what "*give it a voronoi or cloudy look*" and "*saturated glass/hologram like appearance*" means. It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, maybe post some example images. Are the images above the effect you want to achieve? Are you reffering to the darkened gradient at the center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the cloudy effect, create a cloud texture and mix it into the image with a [Mix node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/mix.html). I find a Soft light mix type looks about right.

For the split RGB look you use the [SeparateRGB and CombineRGB](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/converter/combine_separate.html#separate-combine-rgba-node) nodes with a [Transform node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/distort/transform.html) for each channel using different offsets for each. A [Glare node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/filter/glare.html) set to Fog Glow gives a nice soft glow.

[image: final composite]